# How to post json and get back an json response using ajax with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```js
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun() {
 var x = document.forms["myForm"]["machine_id": "TNTEST004"].value;
 var y = document.forms["myForm"]["wifi_mac_address": "80:56:f2:18:12:11"].value;
 var Url = "http://192.168.1.9:8080/machine_reg/";
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhr.open('POST', Url, true);
 xhr.send(x);
 xhr.send(y);

 xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
 function processRequest(e) {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
 alert(xhr.responseText.headers.Host);
 
 var response1 = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
 document.getElementById("updated_time").innerHTML = response1.updated_time;
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = response1.id;
 }
 }
 }
 }
</script>
</head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<body>
<center>
 Javascript Post Request Test
<br><br> 
 
<form name="myForm">
 <input type="text" placeholder= "machine id" name="machine_id"/>
 <input type="text" placeholder= "wifi mac address" name="wifi_mac_address"/>
 <input type="button" id="Save" onclick="function fun()" value="get_values"/>
</form>
 
<br><br> 
 
<table>
 <tr><td>id :</td><td id="id"></td></tr>
 <tr><td>updated_time :</td><td id="updated_time"></td></tr>
</table>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

http://192.168.1.9:8080/machine_reg/ this is my URL. And its a POST method. Now in this URL, if I POST ("machine_id": "TNTEST004","wifi_mac_address":"80:56:f2:18:12:11") these two JSON datas, it will generate an ID (eg:"id: 3"). I have to pass this two json datas in the text boxes with the submit button and on the button click, I should have the id returned in a alert window. I am bit confused getting an error. resolve this for me using ajax in javascript.

I will pass as like this.

`{
 "machine_id": "TNTEST009",

 "wifi_mac_address": "80:56:f2:18:12:11"
}`

This is the ID generated if I pass the machine ID and the wifi mac address.

`{
"id": 5,
"machine_id": "TNTEST009",
"wifi_mac_address": "80:56:f2:18:12:11",
"auth_token": "",
"updated_time": "2018-05-01T13:14:42.372174Z"
}`

Note:(Use Advanced Rest Client app for referrence if you wanna see how this actually works on the post request.)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hey, could you give us a little more info to help us answer please? Specifically, could you share the code making the AJAX call, the server-side script the AJAX is calling to, and what error you are seeing?

Comment: Please add code. do you need us to write a code ? Please add code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question... But this is how you do an ajax request with jquery.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '/User/PrevalidateLevelThree',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            machine_id: 'TNTEST009',

            wifi_mac_address: '80:56:f2:18:12:11'
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
    });
```

Again, i'm not sure I understand your question but I think this will give you a good start...

Comment: ok this looks fine. but If I post this json values,, then the ID generated must be returned in an alert window. can you help me with that?

Comment: I think you should point out in your answer that this solution relies on jquery. Not everyone wants to use jquery, and it is possible to do Ajax requests without it